# last_query() returns false in Rumbelow's My_Model for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I'm using CodeIgniter with Rumbelow's My_Model:
https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

I want to see the executed Update query and this is my code:

```
$this->user_model->update(1,['username'=>'user']);
var_dump($this->db->last_query());
```

But the second row always returns false.

Comment: Hi, please check that you have set `'save_queries' => true` in /application/config/database.php and instead of var_dump simply echo

Comment: It's true, and echo does not show enything. I's a boolean

Comment: did u  notice its first line `DEPRECATED CodeIgniter base CRUD model`

Comment: Yes, But still usable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query was never executed. Because there was an error in validation.

Answer (score 2):

Please Turn On Db Debug in Database Config And Turn Project Environment to `development` in `index.php`

> application/config/database.php

```
$db['test']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

This Might Help :)